# How to update script developed with Jetpack SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to use Firefox standard add-on update to update my script developed with Jetpack SDK, but how?

Answer (score 2):

```
cfx xpi --update-link http://example.com/addon/latest
        --update-url http://example.com/addon/update_rdf
```

More info: https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b4/docs/dev-guide/addon-development/cfx-tool.html

Answer (score 1):

Jetpack SDK generates regular XPI extensions, so the update situation is the same:

- If you host your extension on the addons.mozilla.org site, your users will update to the newest version of the extension automatically.
- Otherwise, see ungarida's answer and [Extension Versioning, Update and Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extension_Versioning%2c_Update_and_Compatibility) on MDC.